How to use or convert '÷' character in php?
I've got values like 5.6÷7.2.
I search for symbols with:
$has_range = preg_match('/[÷\-\/]/', $option, $matches);

Then, if I try to log $matches[0], I get "�".
Why?

This is a character encoding problem. Make sure you have the correct <meta charset> tag.

Use this: $has_range = preg_match('/(*UTF8)[÷\-\/]/', $option, $matches);

@TUPKAP Thank you, that solved the problem. Maybe you could write your own answer!

Does this answer your question? Matching Unicode letter characters in PCRE/PHP

its certainly an encoding problem, try defining UTF-8 at your php file, and for logging $matches[0] also here:
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output("UTF-8");
$option = "5.6÷7.2";
$has_range = preg_match('/[÷\-\/]/u', $option, $matches);
if ($has_range) {
    error_log(var_export($matches[0], true));
}


Thank you very much, but it's all UTF-8, my php doc, my database collation and encoding... All... UTF-8 is my default since at least 15 years. So yes, it's an encoding issue, but really don't know why it's not UTF-8. preg_match('/(*UTF8)[÷\-\/]/', $option, $matches) was the fastest solution for me.

Very strange tho
